# :nth-child(even/odd) selector with class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply odd/even selectors to all elements in a list with the class parent.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent">green</li>
    <li class="parent">red</li>
    <li>ho ho ho</li>
    <li class="parent">green</li>
    <li class="parent">red</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.parent:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: green;
}

.parent:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}

ul {
    width:100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
}
```

[image]

[Link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3AFd/)

But the colors are resetting. I want the list items to be the color of the text.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You need to apply `nth-child` to the `ul`, not the list.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is

Comment: @CodyGuldner: He wants the "ho ho ho" to not count for purposes of zebra striping.

Comment: @AleksG Hum, I can't get that to work, do you mind showing me in a jsFiddle? Do it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @CodyGuldner Yes, like Jon says

Comment: I would think that `nth-of-type` would work, because the third `li` doesn't have that class. But for some reason it doesn't

Comment: `nth-of-type` only takes the "expanded element name" into account when deciding what "type" means. Since all of the children here are `<li>`s `nth-of-type` is the same as `nth-child`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In general what you want is not possible, but there is a way to achieve the desired behavior for limited numbers of "excluded" elements: the [general sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) `~`.

The idea is that for each occurrence of a non-`.parent` element subsequent `.parent` elements will have their colors toggled:

```
.parent:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: green;
}
.parent:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}

/* after the first non-.parent, toggle colors */
li:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: red;
}
li:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: green;
}

/* after the second non-.parent, toggle again */
li:not(.parent) ~ li:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: green;
}
li:not(.parent) ~ li:not(.parent) ~ .parent:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: red;
}
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/H8jCm/)**.

Of course there is a limit to how far one would be willing to take this, but it's as close as you can get with pure CSS.

Comment: @ScottS: Definitely. In general one should go with JS here, but there may be fringe cases where the technique is useful.

Comment: Hello in 2020. For guys who will look for solution. This one doesn`t work well.
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/f6h9vm5o/

Comment: @Kazbek the idea here is that you need to repeat the last two CSS declarations, adding a `li:not(.parent) ~` in front each time and swapping the colors. You need to do this as many times as there will be `:not(.parent)` items, and then it works as intended: https://jsfiddle.net/oncL3dva/.

Granted this is not practical and you'd be much better off using JS for this, but it works in 2020 as well as it worked in 2013.

Answer (score 13):

### This is a common misperception

The `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` selectors do not look at "class" or anything else for counting. They only look at either (1) all elements, or (2) all elements of a certain "type" (not *class*, not an *attribute*, nothing but the *type* of element--`div` or `li` etc.).

So you cannot skip it with pure CSS without either knowing your exact html structure (and then, only if there are in fact a few elements you are dealing with--see Jon's answer for one such way, where you need to know how many non-parent elements you are dealing with, and as you can see and he notes the practical limits are very small), or by using javascript.

Answer (score 6):

It will be possible only with CSS Selectors 4 which will have [nth-match](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#the-nth-match-pseudo).

In the existing CSS it can be done only in some limited situations using the general sibling combinator multuple times, like in @Jon's answer or even in a more 'mechanical' way ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/u3AFd/1/)):

```
.parent,
.parent ~ .parent ~ .parent,
.parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent,
.parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent
{
    background-color: green;
}

.parent ~ .parent,
.parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent,
.parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent,
.parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent ~ .parent
{
    background-color: red;
}
```

In practice, it seems better to me to use JS/jQuery for this.

Answer (score 4):

## CSS

The other reliable way to replicate this currently is with the adjacent sibling selector:

```
.parent,
.parent + .parent + .parent,
.parent + .parent + .parent + .parent + .parent /* etc */
{ background-color: green; }

.parent + .parent,
.parent + .parent + .parent + .parent /* etc */
{ background-color: red; }
```

You have three options:

- Use the `not()` selector. This will keep your highlighting going indefinitely, but it **will occasionally flip the order that it highlights in**. Use this option if your list could have huge groupings of the elements you want to highlight.
- Use the `+` (adjacent sibling) selector. This option **will not keep highlighting indefinitely**, but it guarantees that the order will never be flipped. Use this option if your list will have smaller groupings of highlighted elements together.
- Use the `~` (any sibling) selector. **I would not recommend this as the list will fail to highlight properly based on total list length rather than total matching siblings**. This will always fail before the other two options, and more noticeably.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/corymcd/kVcZJ/

Feel free to copy the HTML from this and paste it into the ones that the other people demonstrated their methods with.

## jQuery

As stated before, using something like jQuery would easily allow you to either assign your elements even/odd classes or simply change the inline style.

```
// Find all objects to highlight, remove all of the highlighting classes, 
// and then re-highlight.
$(".parent").removeClass('odd even').each(function(index) {
    var objPrev = $(this).prev('.parent');
    if( objPrev.hasClass('odd') ) {
        $(this).addClass('even');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('odd');
    }    
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/corymcd/kAPvX

Comment: $(".data_wrapper").removeClass('oddBg evenBg').each(function(index) {
    if(index % 2 == 0){
      $(this).addClass('oddBg');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('evenBg');
    }
  });

Comment: <style>.oddBg{
 background: #FFF;
}
.evenBg{
 background: #f1f4f5;
}</style>