# CSS siblings after a class

Tags: css, sass

I'm currently able to get a zebra table by doing the following:

```
tbody
  tr:nth-child(2n+2)
    background-color: #f3f7f9

  tr:nth-child(2n+1)
    background-color: #fff

  tr.row-headers + tr
    background-color: #fff

  tr.row-headers + tr + tr
    background-color: #f3f7f9
```

For the rows after the tr.row-headers, I'm able to force the 1st row to be #fff and the 2nd to be #f3f7f9 using "+ tr" and "+ tr + tr" respectively, but I don't want to have to do this for the remainder of the rows following.  I tried the nth-child(2n+1) and nth-child(2n+2) instead of the "+ tr" method but that doesnt seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: The title sounds like the start of a joke. :)

Comment: Maybe answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458582/css-selectors-nth-childeven-odd-with-class/) can help?

Answer (score 1):

```
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: #fff; }

tr:nth-child(odd) { background-color: #f3f7f9; }
```

Is that what you're after?

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/RdVHH/)

or in the other syntax:

```
tbody
  tr:nth-child(even)
    background-color: #f3f7f9

  tr:nth-child(odd)
    background-color: #fff
```