# CSS target every even of specific class

Tags: css

looking for answer to this for a few hours and no luck

```
1  <div class="card100"></div>
2  <div class="card50"></div>
3  <div class="card50"></div>
4  <div class="card100"></div>
5  <div class="card50"></div>
6  <div class="card50"></div>
7  <div class="card50"></div>
8  <div class="card50"></div>
```

I need to target every even class of "card50" without consideration "card100" (lines 2,5,7)

is there any CSS only solution for this? .card50:nth-of-type(even) includes lines with .card100 class

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I suggest you'd use Javascript for this.

Comment: Or look at this answer. Somebody had the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17458867/5418514