# Seperate styling for 3 alternate li's

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im working on a project and im using ul and li's.

I have to change background for 3 alternate li's. since list item is coming from backend I won't be knowing about number of list item.

I tried with css3 child classes but couldn't able to achieve.. Is there any way i can achieve this with css or jquery?

```css
.list-item li
{
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
</ul>
```

same background color for list 1,2,3,7,8 and 9 and different background color for list 4,5 and 6.

**As you can see in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyVg7.png), Here I am using table and   I am achieving this using nth-child(even)/(odd) property.because of few restrictions I can't use table here. So need to achieve this using li's.**

Comment: Please put code and markup which you have done so far and jsfiddle will be best to help you out in no time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [:nth-child(even/odd) selector with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17458582/nth-childeven-odd-selector-with-class)

Comment: @Mohtisham i have included code snippet

Comment: @Sandrooco i want to seperate 3 alternative li's ..not like that

Comment: look at my answer. every 3 `li`s are colored as a table rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to style `6n`th, `6n-1`th and `6n-2`th items:

```css
.list-item li
{
  width:30%;
  display:inline-block;
  background: #cfc;
 }
.list-item li:nth-child(6n-2),
.list-item li:nth-child(6n-1),
.list-item li:nth-child(6n){
  background: #ccf;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-item">
  <li>list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li>list item 3</li>
  <li>list item 4</li>
  <li>list item 5</li>
  <li>list item 6</li>
  <li>list item 7</li>
  <li>list item 8</li>
  <li>list item 9</li>
  <li>list item 10</li>
  <li>list item 11</li>
  <li>list item 12</li>
  <li>list item 13</li>
  <li>list item 14</li>
  <li>list item 15</li>
  <li>list item 16</li>
  <li>list item 17</li>
  <li>list item 18</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to achieve this?

To change styling for every third item use `:nth-child()` with i.e. 3n+0 as an argument. If you solve that equation when counting n from 0 upwards you will get the indexes of the items which will be addressed.

Btw:

2n+0 in other words is even
2n+1 in other words is odd

edit:

I added a JS function for achieving something like alternating rows like in the picture which was added in the question later. Have a look at the fiddle!

```js
var alternate = (function() {

  var count = 0;
  var flipAt = 3;
  var condition = false;

  function init(num) {
    flipAt = num;
  }
  
  function process() {
    if(count === flipAt) {
      condition = condition ? false : true;
      count = 0;
    }
    count++;
    return condition ? true : false;
  }

  return {
    init : init,
    process : process
  }
})()


$('li').each(function(index, el) {
  if (alternate.process()) {
    $(el).css('background', 'blue');
  }
});
```

```css
li:nth-child(3n+0) {
    background: red;
}

li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
    <li>14</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response .. I am looking for seperate style for 3 alternate li's ..if yu look at the image I attached yu will get the clear idea

Comment: Yup, saw that later - and fiddled some JS - but have a look at Banzays CSS only answer!

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use following CSS

```
li:nth-child(3n+0) {
    background: red;
}
li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: green;
}
li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: blue;
}
```

> for working example [Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/g9cLw3x7/1/)

Comment: thumbs up, great way